# Авторизация в Spring Security

Tags: веб-программирование, spring-boot, websocket, spring-security, oauth

Конфиг для spring security

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/js/**", "/error**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

По идее при заходе на главную страницу пользователь должен по ссылке авторизоваться через гугл (oAuth), но этого не происходит. Вся моя задумка перестала работать после того как я добавил @ComponentScan в класс запуска spring application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("util")
public class Runner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Runner.class, args);
  }
}
```

Но если я не добавляю аннотацию ComponentScan вылазит другая проблема в виде ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот класс, в котором возникает ошибка

```
@Component
public class WSSender {
private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public WSSender(SimpMessagingTemplate template, ObjectMapper objectMapper){
    this.simpMessagingTemplate = template;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}

public <T> BiConsumer<EventType, T> getSender(ObjectType type, Class view){
    ObjectWriter object = objectMapper
            .setSerializationConfig(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig())
            .writerWithView(view);
    return (EventType event, T payload) -> {
        String value = null;
        try {
            value = object.writeValueAsString(payload);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/activity", new WSEventDto(type, event, value));
    };
}
```

Вообще мне кажется, что ответ лежит где-то на поверхности, но никак не могу додумать, что не так

[image: Требуется авторизоваться]

Comment: Судя по ошибке у вас отсутствует бин ObjectMapper. Попробуйте найти с помощью глобального поиска (Intellij Idea Ctrl+N) класс JacksonAutoConfiguration. Если его нет, то скорее всего вам нужно самому создать бин ObjectMapper'a в конфигурации

Comment: Я в принципе не вижу у вас в конфигурации SS включения OAuth для гугла